# Find biggest prime number divides the number $4+3^{12}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the biggest prime number dividing the number $4+3^{12}$

My try :

$4+3^{12}=2^{2}+(3^{6})^{2}+4\cdot3^{6}-4\cdot3^{6}$

$=(2+3^{6})^{2}-(2\cdot3^{3})^{2}$

$=(2+3^{6}+2\cdot3^{3})(2+3^{6}-2\cdot3^{3})$

$=783\cdot679$

$=3^{3}\cdot29\cdot7\cdot97$

So by my solution the prime number is $97$

Am I correct ?

Is there any other method ?

Comment: Well , the biggest prime factor is actually $677$

Comment: $2+3^{6}+2\cdot 3^{3}=785$ and $2+3^{6}-2\cdot 3^{3}=677$. ($3^{16}$ is a typo.)

Comment: The best way would be to simply evaluate $4+3^{12}$  , which is only $531445$ whose factors can be calculated by hand.

Comment: How is that a better way than the proposed way?

Comment: Note that you have essentially applied the Sophie Germain identity (https://brilliant.org/wiki/sophie-germain-identity/). If you were familiar with this identity, you could have done this in one step :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a mistake in your calculation .

$$(2+3^6 + 2\cdot3^3) = \color{red}{785}$$

While

$$(2+3^6 - 2\cdot3^3) = \color{blue}{677}$$

So , $(4+3^{12}) = (2+3^6 + 2\cdot3^3)(2+3^6 -  2\cdot3^3) = 785\cdot677 = \color{#2c0}{5\cdot157\cdot677} $

And we get the highest prime factor as $677.$

Comment: In other words, the OP forgot to add the $2$ in the first factor.